# Team Foundation Server terminates CMD/Batch/Powershell task

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, pipeline, devops

I try to write build steps in TFS build definition, one of which is calling a CMD running bat script of SoapUI located in file system:

C:\"Program Files"\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner

This bat script runs test steps with *.xml file in repository.

After this step is running TFS tries to terminate script sending SIGBREAK (CTRL_C) and then CMD step is stopping with message "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?".

The problem is certainly in this bat script, because other scripts work fine. 
The same happens with Batch and Powershell too.
Can I prevent this behavior in TFS?

P.S. I find interesting that in file system logs TFS writes following:
`Stop aggressive process web console line queue.`

P.S.S. Script needs internet access to send requests to web-service.

TFS logs:

```
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6310955Z ##[section]Starting: Run Tests
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6314476Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6314575Z Task         : Batch Script
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6314677Z Description  : Run a windows cmd or bat script and optionally allow it to change the environment
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6314760Z Version      : 1.1.3
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6314831Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6314926Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613733)
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6315025Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-15T13:23:30.6326914Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat" -r -j -ftests %testScript% 2>NUL
2019-04-15T13:23:31.7381481Z 18:23:31,483 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\soapui-settings.xml]
2019-04-15T13:23:33.0767434Z 18:23:32,679 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 2 ms
2019-04-15T13:23:33.0767679Z 18:23:32,679 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
2019-04-15T13:24:22.9158044Z Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
2019-04-15T13:24:22.9249350Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2019-04-15T13:24:22.9280244Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Tests
```

I also found the following logs in file system C:\agent_diag

```
[2019-04-15 12:13:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Process started with process id 7868, waiting for process exit.
[2019-04-15 12:13:40Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record '5119da93-a929-543c-7e43-439284c14c5d', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-04-15 12:13:40Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'b544018b-4d71-5134-742f-cb63728506de', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-04-15 12:13:40Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record '85f1bd98-2921-5766-8330-d8b491fc5b96', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-04-15 12:13:43Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record '85f1bd98-2921-5766-8330-d8b491fc5b96', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-04-15 12:13:43Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to upload 2 log files or attachments, success rate: 2/2.
[2019-04-15 12:13:44Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record '85f1bd98-2921-5766-8330-d8b491fc5b96', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-04-15 12:13:51Z INFO JobServerQueue] Stop aggressive process web console line queue.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO Worker] Cancellation/Shutdown message received.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ExpressionManager] Evaluating: succeeded()
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ExpressionManager] Result: False
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO StepsRunner] Cancel current running step.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Sending CTRL_C to process 7868.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Successfully send CTRL_C to process 7868.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Waiting for process exit or 7.5 seconds after CTRL_C signal fired.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Ignore Ctrl+C to current process.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Finished process with exit code 1, and elapsed time 00:04:49.0108550.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z ERR  StepsRunner] Caught cancellation exception from step: System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.<ExecuteAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.PowerShellExeHandler.<RunAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.<RunStepAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO StepsRunner] Step result: Canceled
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO StepsRunner] No need for updating job result with current step result 'Canceled'.
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO StepsRunner] Current state: job state = 'Canceled'
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO StepsRunner] Processing step: DisplayName='Post Job Cleanup', ContinueOnError=False, Enabled=True
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ExpressionManager] Evaluating: AlwaysNode()
[2019-04-15 12:18:29Z INFO ExpressionManager] Result: True`
```

Comment: The termination happen after the tests are completed? if you should able to press "y" it's will be fine? or your issue it the why the task terminated?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I'm not sure that tests complete because I cannot get any info about status of task. The main problem is that I also cannot press anything because TFS runs this script and script waits for TFS to press. So the situation looks like "deadlock" where TFS is waiting for script to complete, and script waits for TFS to press anything.

Comment: Can you share the batch file?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes, please: [link](https://codeshare.io/5O0j1N). Note: that's not my code. It comes with SoapUI installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by re-installing SoapUI.

Not sure why it happens, but TFS doesn't work clearly with SoapUI 5.2.1